# iOS App with Static keyboard while view Transistion - App store guideline check

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, appstore-approval

We have two screens in our app namely Screen A and Screen B, which has UITextfields in them, Keyboard appears on the first screenn on completing the details in first screen , the secondview appears automatically via animation and keyboard is NOT dismissed and it stays in the screen during this Transistion between screens. Is this aceptable behaviour in iOS or will the app be rejected for this behaviour ?

To be precise, We do not dismiss and render the keyboard when there is a screen transistion, Keypad remains on the screen while moving from one screen to another screen

Answer (score 0):

Don't think Apple will reject it but this is not acceptable in case of user perspective or not a good design approach.
Why you are not using,

```
[self.view endEditing:TRUE];
```

Just before the transition , so that the keyboard disappears and you can again enable the keyboard after the  completion of transition to Screen B.So the keyboard will hide in the transition phase.

You can enable it in your - `viewDidAppear()` method - just by activating keyboard for your first textfeild/textview using

```
[self.textField becomeFirstResponder]
```

This approach is much applicable , I guess.